# Use tmux plugins with Powerline

Tags: plugins, tmux, powerline

I was using GNUScreen and recently I migrated to tux. I'm now searching the available plugins and I'm trying to understand how I can use them. Specifically, I have successfully installed Powerline and I can alter the colours etc. Though, I cannot understand how to use tmux plugins from tmux plugin manager (tpm) into Powerline.

Is there any resource that shows an example how one has integrated a tmux plugin into Powerline? For example, one of those two:

- https://github.com/imomaliev/tmux-keyboard-layout
- https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-battery

Just to be clear, **I don't want to use Powerline segments, I want to integrate tmux plugins.**

Any help, online resource, explanation, or example is are welcome!